# Drag and drop animated GIFs rendered in NSImageView Swift MacOS application

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, gif

I am trying to build a Mac OSX application that renders several gifs and allows the users to drag and drop them for copying the gifs into some other app. I am using a `DragDropImageView` (code below) that conforms to an `NSImageView` to render a gif that is drag-n-drop enabled.

It works fine, except that **when I drag and drop the gif into another application, it copies only a single image frame of the gif.** My intention is to copy the entire gif file and not just a single image.

I am pretty new to iOS/MacOS development in general, and I am not sure if my approach to building this draggable gif component is correct.

I am building the app using swiftUI, and I use a custom view called `GifImageView` that converts the `DragDropImageView` to a swiftUI view.

`DragDropImageView.swift`

```
import Cocoa

class DragDropImageView: NSImageView, NSDraggingSource {

    /// Holds the last mouse down event, to track the drag distance.
    var mouseDownEvent: NSEvent?

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        isEditable = false
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        // Assure editable is set to true, to enable drop capabilities.
        isEditable = true
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    // MARK: - NSDraggingSource
    // Since we only want to copy the current image we register
    // for .Copy operation.
    func draggingSession(_: NSDraggingSession,
                         sourceOperationMaskFor _: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
        return NSDragOperation.copy
    }

//    // Clear the ImageView on delete operation; e.g. the image gets
//    // dropped on the trash can in the dock.
//    func draggingSession(_: NSDraggingSession, endedAt _: NSPoint,
//                         operation: NSDragOperation) {
//        if operation == .delete {
//            image = nil
//        }
//    }

    // Track mouse down events and safe the to the poperty.
    override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        mouseDownEvent = theEvent
    }

    // Track mouse dragged events to handle dragging sessions.
    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {

        // Calculate the dragging distance...
        let mouseDown = mouseDownEvent!.locationInWindow
        let dragPoint = event.locationInWindow
        let dragDistance = hypot(mouseDown.x - dragPoint.x, mouseDown.y - dragPoint.y)

        // Cancel the dragging session in case of an accidental drag.
        if dragDistance < 3 {
            return
        }

        guard let image = self.image else {
            return
        }

        let draggingImage = image

        // Create a new NSDraggingItem with the image as content.
        let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: image)

        // Calculate the mouseDown location from the window's coordinate system to the
        // ImageView's coordinate system, to use it as origin for the dragging frame.
        let draggingFrameOrigin = convert(mouseDown, from: nil)
        // Build the dragging frame and offset it by half the image size on each axis
        // to center the mouse cursor within the dragging frame.
        let draggingFrame = NSRect(origin: draggingFrameOrigin, size: draggingImage.size)
            .offsetBy(dx: -draggingImage.size.width / 2, dy: -draggingImage.size.height / 2)

        // Assign the dragging frame to the draggingFrame property of our dragging item.
        draggingItem.draggingFrame = draggingFrame

        // Provide the components of the dragging image.
        draggingItem.imageComponentsProvider = {
            let component = NSDraggingImageComponent(key: NSDraggingItem.ImageComponentKey.icon)

            component.contents = image
            component.frame = NSRect(origin: NSPoint(), size: draggingFrame.size)
            return [component]
        }

        // Begin actual dragging session. Woohow!
        beginDraggingSession(with: [draggingItem], event: mouseDownEvent!, source: self)
    }
}
```

`GifImageView.swift`

```
import AppKit;
import SwiftUI;

struct GifImageView: NSViewRepresentable {
    var image: NSImage
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> DragDropImageView {
        let view = DragDropImageView()
        view.image = self.image
//        view.allowsCutCopyPaste = true
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: DragDropImageView, context: Context) {
        
    }

}

struct GifImageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GifImageView(image: NSImage(data: (NSDataAsset(name: "tenor")?.data)!)!)
    }
}
```

in my `ContentView.swift`, I use my `GifImageView` something like this:

```
GifImageView(image: *some NSImage*)
```

Comment: Forgive me, but what caught my eye was drag/drop, which I'll be dealing with in about a week with my app. Reading through you question? Twice (including the question title) you state **MacOS** but yet twice (including a tag) you state **iOS**.  I think it's improperly tagged. Your code has `include Cocoa` and `include AppKit`, that indicates (to me) you are **not** talk iOS (which is `UIKit`). One last thing - are you talking an animated GIF?

Comment: Yes, I mean animated gifs. Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that your drag fetches the image view's `image`. But that is _not_ the animated gif. It is just a single frame of the animated gif. If you want to drag and drop the animated gif you need to retrieve the original _file_. The file is the animated gif.

Comment: But even when calling my `GifImageView`, I pass the gif as an `NSImage` to it, and it manages to play the gif correctly. Then why does dragging the `NSImage` cause it to copy just the image and not the gif?

Having said that, I would like to try out your suggestion. Is there a way to drag the file instead of the `image`? I don't know of an easy way to retrieve the file from the `NSImage`.